# How can I figure out what is the default standard used by my C compiler GCC ?

Tags: c, gcc, c99, c11, c89

Everything is in the title, I searched a lot but cannot find what is the standard that uses my compiler is it C89 C90 C99 or C11 ... I mean when we do not specify the -std option ( the default one) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in doubt, consult the documentation. The [gcc man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) makes it clear that `-std=gnu89` is the default for C code, and `-std=gnu++98` is the default for C++ code. The meaning of these options is described both in the man page and, in much more detail, in the extensive info documentation that is [also available online](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Standards.html#Standards).

These defaults for these flags have changed before and will change again, so it is best to check before assuming specific values.

**UPDATE**
The defaults have changed over the years. As of GCC 8.3.0, released in February 2019, [the default](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Standards.html#Standards) standard for C is `-std=gnu11`, and `-std=gnu++14` for C++. To be sure, look at the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) of the compiler version you are actually using.

Comment: Thanks to  you I found what I was looking for **gnu89
GNU dialect of ISO C90 (including some C99 features). This is the default for C code.** :D

Answer (score 5):

gcc comes with extensive documentation.

Type `info gcc` and read the "Standards" section of the manual.

For most recent compilers (going back quite a few years), the default is `-std=gnu90`, which implements the 1990 ISO C standard (equivalent to the 1989 ANSI C standard) with some GNU-specific extensions.

(I'd point you to the gcc manual on the web, but that would document the latest version, not the one you're using. I presume your documentation is for the same version you're using.)

Comment: I probably should have remembered that I posted the accepted answer to the duplicate question.  8-)}